# UIWebview loads with blank page

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview

i have table view contains documents list which pushes to web-view on cell click,correct file path passed from table view to web-view,but web-view loads with blank pages. Here is the code i used

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowPDF"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    PDFViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* inboxPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Inbox"];
dirFiles = [filemgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:inboxPath error:nil];
destViewController.path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[dirFiles  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
}
```

To load webview i use the below code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

   NSString *filePath =path;
   NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[pdfView loadRequest:request];
[pdfView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
   NSLog(@"%@", self.pdfView);

}
```

Need help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue, error in this below line

```
destViewController.path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[dirFiles  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

replaced it with below line

```
destViewController.path = [inboxPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[dirFiles  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```